# SQL: No data for one date, complete with the next one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cross-join

I have this SQL table

```
date    value
2014-01-02 00:00:00.000 524,61
2014-01-03 00:00:00.000 529,55
2014-01-04 00:00:00.000 NULL
2014-01-05 00:00:00.000 NULL
2014-01-06 00:00:00.000 528,80
2014-01-07 00:00:00.000 531,14
2014-01-08 00:00:00.000 531,65
2014-01-09 00:00:00.000 532,14
2014-01-10 00:00:00.000 533,97
2014-01-11 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

I need to complete all the NULL values with the next no-null value.

thanks

Comment: Define 'next value'. The value on the next date ?

Comment: Which is your DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)?

Comment: And please add some info about your data model (query, tables...)

Comment: Next no-null value = Value with a higher date but is no null.

Comment: MSSQL Server 2008 10.50.6000.34

Comment: I suppose OP need to fill the `NULL`s with next `NOT NULL` value (I suppose order  by date). So when on `2014-01-04` there is `NULL` the value must be set from `2014-01-06`, becase on `2014-01-05` the `value` is also `NULL`. The same `value` will be allied on `2014-01-05`.

Comment: Are the dates consequitive?

Comment: The dates can be no consequitive and there is cases with more than 10 NULL's in a row.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `SELECT` that does what you want:

```
select t.date, t2.value
from table t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from table t2
      where t2.date <= t.date and t2.value is not null
      order by t2.date desc
     ) t2;
```

This can also be phrased as an `update`, if you want to actually set the values in the data.

Comment: this query returns `524.61` as value for all the rows

Comment: @SmartDev . . . Yes, ordering in the `cross apply` needs to be in the correct direction, so the first value is not always returned,

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE DATE:**

```
declare @tbl table (Date INT, val INT)
insert into @tbl values(1,524), (2,529), (3,NULL), (4,NULL), (5,531)
```

**QUERY**

```
select Date, 
       coalesce(val,(select top 1 val 
                     from @tbl t2 
                     where val is not null and t1.Date < t2.Date
                     )
                ) Col_Without_NULLS
from @tbl t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all
The code was fine, but the > was in the opposite direction

```
select t.date, t2.value
from #test t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from #test t2
      where t.date <= t2.date and
       t2.value is not null
      order by t2.date
     ) t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select 
    M.date, isnull(M.value, min(S.value)) as value  
from 
    @data M
    left outer join @data S on M.date < S.date and S.value is not null
group by
    M.date, M.value
order 
    by M.date
```